# Mapbox Terrain: Reference DEM values in a Style expression

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to retrieve DEM elevation values for use in a Mapbox Style expression?

Case in point - I'm using a custom DEM for terrain in Mapbox GL-JS. I would like to set the exaggeration based on the elevation value (lower terrain, higher exaggeration) via an interpolate expression.

```js
// Pseudo code
map.setTerrain({
  source: 'custom-dem',
  exaggeration: [
    'interpolate',
    ['linear'],
    ['get', 'z'], // ???
    0, 2.5,
    100, 1.5,
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any mechanism to retrieve the height of terrain within an expression, so no.

In any case, according to [the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/terrain/) the `terrain` type only has `basic functionality` (ie, not data-driven expressions), so you can't do what you're trying to do for that reason, too.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yep, that SDK support note was what I was looking for. Not loving the new documentation. As an FYI you can actually retrieve the height of terrain for properties that support data-driven styling. I've previously used it to colourise a fill-extrusion layer, it's a really nice effect. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, what expression lets you do that?

Comment: Fairly sure it's as simple as `["get", "z"]` ... for my use case I had exported a DEM using a custom height profile, so as to encode more detail within a specific elevation range (I was actually dealing with depth, so from 0m to -200m) ... and then displayed it using a fill extrusion layer. I had to decode on the front-end in an expression, e.g. ```fill-extrusion-height":["interpolate",["linear"],["get","z"],-200,["*",["/",["get","z"],100],2000],-100,["+",["*",["/",["get","z"],100],1000],1000],1,["+",["*",["get","z"],2],1000]]``` here's the end result: https://lab.citizensgbr.org/census-map/

Comment: Was basically wanting to to the same thing with terrain so I could map it to a pretty satellite layer :)